# GreenWithEnvy's overclocking menu has no overclocking sliders

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, gpu

So, I did what a tutorial said and I set coolbits to 8.  As expected, GreenWithEnvy's overclocking menu became available. However, when I tried to make a custom overclock setting, the overclock profile box popped up without the overclocking sliders [image: Take a look here]

I'm using a NVIDIA Tesla P4 graphics card and my system is Linux Mint 21.1 Vera

Comment: which tutorial? Please link to it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don’t remember the exact link, but the tutorial said for me to add an option called ‘Option “Coolbits” “8”’ in the /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that my specific GPU has no overclocking feature, thus no sliders appeared.  For anybody else who had a similar problem with their headless/workstation GPU in Linux, you can see which clocks are supported by your GPU with the
`nvidia-smi -i 0 --query-supported-clocks=mem,gr --format=csv`
bash command.